# Why @override of "get" here? (syntax in Dart)

Tags: dart

In [this](https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/master/provider_shopper/lib/models/catalog.dart) official Flutter example there is a class, which does not extend another class. So why `int get hashCode` has `@override` over it? I.e. there is nothing to override, no?

```
class Item {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final Color color;
  final int price = 42;

  Item(this.id, this.name)
      // To make the sample app look nicer, each item is given one of the
      // Material Design primary colors.
      : color = Colors.primaries[id % Colors.primaries.length];

  @override
  int get hashCode => id;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) => other is Item && other.id == id;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [hashCode property documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html#:%7E:text=All%20objects%20have%20hash%20codes,are%20identical%20(see%20identityHashCode).):

> All objects have hash codes. The default hash code represents only the identity of the object, the same way as the default operator == implementation only considers objects equal if they are identical (see identityHashCode).

And from [Object class documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Object-class.html)

> Because Object is the root of the Dart class hierarchy, every other Dart class is a subclass of Object.

Every class is a subclass of the `Object class`, therefore they will always have the same properties of it and this is what you are overriding.

And now if you are asking why to override both `hashCode` and `equals`, check [this link about hash_and_equals lint rules](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/hash_and_equals)

Answer (score 2):

From the official [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html)

> A hash code is a single integer which represents the state of the object that affects operator == comparisons. All objects have hash codes. The default hash code represents only the identity of the object, the same way as the default operator == implementation only considers objects equal if they are identical (see identityHashCode).

In other words every time you create an object of class Item, you generate a hashCode property for it as well.

So now if you want to check equality of two objects of class item, Dart (like Java) will check the equality by doing `==` of the hashcode.

Which means that `Item object1 != Item Object2` since each object will have its own unique hashcode.

Hence, the hashcode has to be overriden, in this case so that `Item object1` can be checked for equality with `Item object2`